# How to parsing JSON like this?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jsonparser

I have json data format like

```
{
   "status":200,
   "message":"ok",
   "response": {"result":1, "time": 0.0123, "values":[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
   }
}
```

I want to get one value of values array and put it on textView in eclipse. Look my code in eclipse

```
protected void onPostExecute (String result){
try {
JSONobject json = new JSONObject(result);
tv.setText(json.toString(1));
}catch (JSONException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: You code seems to be missing some parts. Where is the `try` and where does the function close?

Answer (score 1):

You can use GSON

Create a POJO for your response

```
public class Response{
   private int result;
   private double time;
   private ArrayList<Integer> values;

   // create SET's and GET's
}
```

And then use GSON to create the object you desire.

```
protected void onPostExecute (String result){
  try {
     Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
     Response p = gson.fromJson(result, Response.class);
     tv.setText(p.getValues());
  }catch (JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much joao86's, your code have been helped me, that's working but i want get  values array by index. What sould i do for this ? Please

Comment: @ahsanasha07 what do you mean by `get values array by index.`? If you want to get the value in a certain position of the array, just do `p.getValues().get(position)`

Comment: Yes sir, i want get the value in certain position of the array. I  try p.getValues().get(position) not working.

Comment: what happens when you use it?

Comment: When i running project, application is close itself

Comment: print to the log what the result of p.getValues()

Comment: Java.lang.NullPointerException
at skr.example.skripsi.home$HttpAsyncTask.onPosExecute(home.java: 215) 
at skr.example.skripsi
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsynchTask.java:417)

Comment: what is the string you are receiving onPostExecute?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jackson library for json parsing.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map map = mapper.readTree(json);
map.get("key");
```

You can use readTree if you know json is an instance of JSONObject class else use typeref and go with readValue to get the map.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void onPostExecute (String result){
    try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONObject resp = json.getJSONObject("response");
JSONArray jarr = resp.getJSONArray("values");
     tv.setText(jarr.get(0).toString(1));
    }catch (JSONException e){
     e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
     }
```

Comment: Thank bro, now is working. I just change tv.setText(jarr.get(0).toStirng(1)); into 
tv.setText(jarr.get(0).toString()); done

Comment: You can vote me up if it helped. Or mark it as answered.